# SQL convert into XML gets error: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that gets a XML response into a temp table.

Another procedure takes it from the table into a `varchar(max)` variable, then converts it to XML.

Here I get an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure bla, Line 17
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

It happens when it inserts the XML into a XML value.

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max)
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @x =( SELECT response 
        From tmp)
--error on next line
SELECT @xml = CONVERT(XML,@x,2)
```

This worked fine for a while, now every time I run it I get this error.

The response is not large at all, 14 KB.

Thanks

Comment: try different values for the 3rd parameter of the convert function.  Valid values when converting to xml are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Doesn't help, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way that works: (but I steel don't understand why it happened.)

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml =( SELECT response 
        From tmp for XML auto)
```